# Why Are There Some IOS App's That Are Capable Of Not Utilizing Have To Use The In-App Purchase?

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore, in-app-purchase

I am a Malaysian App Developer, and my team and I are currently in midst of developing an iOS app, and have come across a few questions which I hope stackexchange will be able to answer.

1) We have found that most POS Apps listed within the following article, [Best iPad Restaurant POS Systems of 2016 | Top Ten Reviews](http://pos-systems-review.toptenreviews.com/ipad-restaurant/), do not utilize the IAP for their monetary transactions. We have examined each App individually, and have found that their transaction methods range from Customized Payment Systems, Membership-Based Payment Systems, to Portal-Based Payment Systems. Considering Apple Inc's stance on Transactions, App Store Review Guidelines, Clause 11: Purchasing & Currencies, is their method of Monetary Transactions considered to be transgressing Apple Inc's standing policies and/or is illegal ?

Please kindly advise on the queries that I have raised and explain in detail, if their actions are completely illegal or the result of abusing a loophole within Apple Inc's policies.

Comment: You should separate your question into two. People here must be able to find the answer to the question in your title.

Answer (score 1):

POS applications do not use IAPs for payments because:

1. IAPs are made for purchases of parts of applications, not goods outside the App Store. For example Amazon app or Bookings do not use IAPs
2. Apple takes a 30% cut on each IAP. This is not bearable in a low margin business such as restoration.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but seems your reply stand on restaurant view, not our program view.
Obviously they are selling parts of application, they let user use some of the part in demo and use money to unlock the other parts. they are not selling goods like Fruits or Books outside the AppStore.